# How get setInterval for every objects?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Subj

I have javascript code, example

```
var User = function(data){
  this.name = data.name;
  this.delay = data.delay;
  this.say();
}

User.prototype.say = function(){
  _self = this;
  setInterval(function(){
    console.log(_self.name);
  }, this.delay * 1000);
}



var u1 = new User({name: "user1", delay: 10});
var u2 = new User({name: "user2", delay: 15});
```

u1 and u2 object returns **user2**.

How return **user1** through 10 seconds and return **user2** through 15 seconds ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of how closures work.  You are not creating a new copy of `_self` for each `setInterval` as you are thinking because the variable is in the global scope, so the last one created overwrites the first value.

Try this:

```
var User = function(data){
  this.name = data.name;
  this.delay = data.delay;
  this.say();
}

User.prototype.say = function(){
  var _self = this;
    setInterval(function(){
      console.log(_self.name);
  }, this.delay * 1000);
}

var u1 = new User({name: "user1", delay: 10});
var u2 = new User({name: "user2", delay: 15});
```

Each call to the anonymous function creates a new local scope, which is new for each closure created within it, and thus, each scope has it's own value for `_self` when you add `var` before it.

Consider looking at the documentation of [Bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) as well.

Comment: Your solution is overly complicated. Just adding `var` is enough. Yes, the issue is related to closures, but the actual problem is that `_self` is global.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the setInterval function is using a cached version of _self. Try doing this:

```
 var _self = this;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use global variables. Make `_self` local:

```
var _self = ...;
```